# What is the subject line of a Google+ Invite?

Tags: google-plus

What is the phrase in the subject line of a Google+ invite?

Somebody sent me one, and searching for "Google+" in my Gmail account turns up no results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Welcome to the Google+ project***

[image]

Check this link for scams on Google+:
[The first big Google+ spam campaign blasted out by pill-pushers](http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2011/07/01/google-plus-spam/)

Answer (score 2):

Email notifications, including invites, for Google+ are from the mail domain `@plus.google.com` so I'd try searching for that.

I believe the subject line could be anything - in my case it was a message from the person who sent me the invite.